# Durandal nested view composition

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, durandal, composition

We are trying to build SPA Application using Durandal JS as a concept, we have layout where there is top navigation panel and main container where SPA content is loaded. in one of out views, we have left side panel with navigation which should only change right panel of the same view. I know that thee is child rout inside Durandal 2.0, but I am not able to achieve what my goal is. clicking on top panel should change main container (there are tow tabs on top) but on the second tab, where there is extra sub navigation on the left side of loaded view I can not figure out how to make Durandal to only change right panel of same view. I am not asking for code not for concrete implementation, but for concept or theoretical guidelines on how to achieve this.

I even tried using Areas inside durandal 2.0 but that seems to be different from what I want to get as a result.

Comment: You need to include code of what you have tried.  What you are explaining is fairly simple.

Comment: u mean JS part or HTML part of the project? let me prepare samples as I can not directly copy/paste project codes. by the way our initial idea was to have ko.observable ActiveView which would define modulID as its property and then bind that property inside out child view. do u think this is good idea?

Comment: a sample is a good idea.  I've found that, often, when I am struggling with something, if I recreate my problem in an isolated example, I figure it out - it's easier to see clearly what the problem is.

Comment: if your code isn't illuminating, a screenshot or drawing would be great too. too much right panel main panel second tab sub nav to keep track of what it should look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you head back to the Durandal site, download the [HTML samples.zip](http://durandaljs.com/version/latest/HTML%20Samples.zip) file. Fire that bad boy up and you will see that the ko samples are doing exactly what you are looking for.
(copy of the index.js file from the ko samples folder)

```
define(['plugins/router', 'knockout'], function(router, ko) {
    var childRouter = router.createChildRouter()
        .makeRelative({
            moduleId:'ko',
            fromParent:true
        }).map([
            { route: '',                moduleId: 'helloWorld/index',       title: 'Hello World',           type: 'intro' },
            { route: 'helloWorld',      moduleId: 'helloWorld/index',       title: 'Hello World',           type: 'intro',      nav: true},
            { route: 'clickCounter',    moduleId: 'clickCounter/index',     title: 'Click Counter',         type: 'intro',      nav: true},
            { route: 'simpleList',      moduleId: 'simpleList/index',       title: 'Simple List',           type: 'intro',      nav: true },
            { route: 'betterList',      moduleId: 'betterList/index',       title: 'Better List',           type: 'intro',      nav: true},
            { route: 'controlTypes',    moduleId: 'controlTypes/index',     title: 'Control Types',         type: 'intro',      nav: true },
            { route: 'collections',     moduleId: 'collections/index',      title: 'Collection',            type: 'intro' ,     nav: true },
            { route: 'pagedGrid',       moduleId: 'pagedGrid/index',        title: 'Paged Grid',            type: 'intro',      nav: true },
            { route: 'animatedTrans',   moduleId: 'animatedTrans/index',    title: 'Animated Transition',   type: 'intro',      nav: true },
            { route: 'contactsEditor',  moduleId: 'contactsEditor/index',   title: 'Contacts Editor',       type: 'detailed',   nav: true },
            { route: 'gridEditor',      moduleId: 'gridEditor/index',       title: 'Grid Editor',           type: 'detailed',   nav: true },
            { route: 'shoppingCart',    moduleId: 'shoppingCart/index',     title: 'Shopping Cart',         type: 'detailed',   nav: true },
            { route: 'twitterClient',   moduleId: 'twitterClient/index',    title: 'Twitter Client',        type: 'detailed',   nav: true}
        ]).buildNavigationModel();

    return {
        router: childRouter,
        introSamples: ko.computed(function() {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(childRouter.navigationModel(), function(route) {
                return route.type == 'intro';
            });
        }),
        detailedSamples: ko.computed(function() {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(childRouter.navigationModel(), function(route) {
                return route.type == 'detailed';
            });
        })
    };
});
```

Comment: this is very close to what I want to achieve but there is one thing I can not understand. how view composition works in this case? how Durandal knows to load content in right panel instead of main container?

Comment: I think I found what I was looking for as there is something very itneresting in index.html file of Ko samples <!--ko router: { transition:'entrance', cacheViews:true }--><!--/ko-->. is that waht makes child views to be loaded inside left panel?

Comment: yes. that is correct. so long as you are exposing the child router as a router property from the viewmodel.